# Get get_terms alphabetically

Tags: terms

I want to get listing of multiple taxonomies alphabetically,
As the terms are very large in number so will manage using pagination of alphabets,
I want to get_terms query for specific alphabets, for example get listing of all terms start with 'B' or 'C'.
Please guide how can I achieve this.

Following is getting all terms with B in it, its behaving %B%, but I need B%

```
    $args = array(
      'orderby'    => 'name', 
      'order'      => 'ASC',
      'name__like' => 'b',
      'number'     => '20', 
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try tu use name__like as MySQL LIKE :

```
$args = array(
      'orderby'    => 'name', 
      'order'      => 'ASC',
      'name__like' => 'b%',
      'number'     => '20', 
    );
```

Comment: this doesn't help because internally the SLQ result is `t.name LIKE %b%%` --- there is no bulit-in function to do that. you sould filter the result of `get_terms` in a loop to have what you need

Comment: My bad.
Then you need to loop against the result and remove all terms that doesn't match <pre><code>(substr($term_name, 0,1) === $letter)</code></pre>